# Ruby on Rails - Optimization of code for speed creates js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am looking for a best way to Optimize this code , we are creating almost 250 js file in file around 90 lines.

any suggestions

```
 def company_trend_seventy
begin
  @market = Market.find_by_market_opser('TDWL')
  @market.companies.each do |trend|
    f = File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/#{trend.api_id}.js", "w+")
    f.write("var vix = [ \n ")
    seventy = JSON.parse([open("http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=#{trend.api_id}&x=TADAWUL&i=86400&p=90d&f=d,c,o,h,l,v&df=cpct&auto=1&ts=1266701290218").read].to_json)
    @date =  Time.at(seventy.first.strip().split("TIMEZONE_OFFSET=180\n")[1].split("\n").first.split(",")[0][1..-1].to_i)
    seventy.first.strip().split("TIMEZONE_OFFSET=180\n")[1].split("\n").each_with_index do |seventyy,i|
      if i == 0
        new_date = Time.at(seventyy.split(",")[0][1..-1].to_i).strftime("%e-%b-%Y")
      else
        new_date = (@date + seventyy.split(",")[0].to_i.day).strftime("%e-%b-%Y")
      end
      f.write("{ date: '#{new_date}', open: #{seventyy.split(",")[4]}, high: #{seventyy.split(",")[2]}, low: #{seventyy.split(",")[3]}, close: #{seventyy.split(",")[1]}, signal: '0', ret: 0 },\n")
    end
    f.write("];")
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Stock Updated Successfully!"
  redirect_to "/admin/companies"
rescue Exception => ex
  flash[:notice] = "Connection Time out!"
  redirect_to admin_dashboards_path
end
end
```

the out put from the file looks like this

thanks in advance

```
var vix = [ 
 { date: '30-Mar-2014', open: 30.9, high: 31.1, low: 30.6, close: 30.8, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
{ date: '31-Mar-2014', open: 30.9, high: 31.5, low: 30.8, close: 31.4, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
{ date: ' 1-Apr-2014', open: 31.5, high: 31.5, low: 31.2, close: 31.4, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
{ date: ' 2-Apr-2014', open: 31.3, high: 31.7, low: 31.3, close: 31.4, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
{ date: ' 3-Apr-2014', open: 31.9, high: 32.6, low: 31.4, close: 32.1, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
{ date: ' 6-Apr-2014', open: 32.3, high: 32.6, low: 31.8, close: 32.1, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
{ date: ' 7-Apr-2014', open: 32.1, high: 32.1, low: 31.4, close: 31.6, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
{ date: ' 8-Apr-2014', open: 31.7, high: 32, low: 31.5, close: 31.9, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
{ date: ' 9-Apr-2014', open: 31.7, high: 31.9, low: 31.4, close: 31.7, signal: '0', ret: 0 },
```

Comment: This question should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is no meaningful way of optimizing this, you're making 250 network requests for `http://www.google.com/...` which is going to account for virtually all the *measurable* time for which your program runs. The best way to optimize this would be to *not* do that.

Comment: You could use threads to reduce the IO, but you'll likely run out of memory if you create too many threads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing how often you update this data, it is difficult to suggest improvements. If this is only a daily update, then you should schedule all of the data to be updated offline, and only create the files once a day. If the goal is a real time updates to the data then you are definitely going the wrong way on this.

Ultimately, you should not be updating the files during the web request. You should offload the file updates to a scheduler or a queue of some kind (like Sidekiq). Or if you need the data to be updated in real time you need to find a different source and use a WebSocket or Server Sent Events to consume the data. Polling for updates every couple of seconds is also valid.